# $L_1=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos x\cos 2x \cos 3x}{x^2}\;$ and $L_2=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1-(\cos x)^{{(\cos 2x)}^{(\cos 3x)}}}{x^2}\;$

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

If $$L_1=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos x\cos 2x \cos 3x}{x^2}\;$$ and $$L_2=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1-(\cos x)^{{(\cos 2x)}^{(\cos 3x)}}}{x^2},\;$$ then value of $|L_1-L_2|$ is equal to:

**My Approach:**

I put the maclurin series expansion of $\cos x= 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\cdots$ in $\;L_1\;$ and obtained result $\;7$.

When i tried to do same for $\;L_2\;$ it got complicated. Then I put $x=0$ in $(\cos 2x)^{(\cos 3x)}$ so $\;L_2\;$  converted to $\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and i obtained the correct result.

But same thing i tried to do with $L_1,\;$ I obtained $L_1=\dfrac{1}{2}\;,2,\; \dfrac{9}{2}$ Result is $\dfrac{1}{2}$ if I take $\lim_{x \to 0}=\cos 2x \cos 3x =1,\;$ result if $2$ if I take $\lim_{x \to 0}=\cos x \cos 3x =1,\;$ and result is $\dfrac{9}{2}$, If i take $\lim_{x \to 0}=\cos 2x \cos 3x =1,\;$.

$\implies$ I can not put directly those limit in $L_1$. But i can put in $L_2$

**My Doubts:**  $(i)$ When can i put limit directly to expression as I did in $L_2$.

$(ii)$ what are the limitation of approach i took for $L_2$

**I know other method to solve this problem I just want to clear my Doubt**

Comment: Since $(1+a)^{1+b}-1=e^{(1+b)\ln(1+a)}-1\sim(1+b)\ln(1+a)\sim a$ for small $a,\,b$, the exponent $1+b$ doesn't matter in calculating this limit. In other words, $(\cos x)^{(\cos 2x)^{\cos 3x}}$ might as well be $(\cos x)^{\cos 2x}$ and hence $\cos x$. It looks like at times you've considered $\cos 3x\cos 2x$ when it would help more to consider $\cos 3x\ln\cos 2x$.

Comment: In general you are not allowed to replace part of an expression with its limit. Instead use limit laws. In short the approach used is invalid and should not be used at all.